# How can I call the data I want with mongoose query or aggregate in next js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, aggregate, aggregation

my data

```
parentid:2,
id:4,
mlgName : {
  "en": "englishname"
  "tr": "turkceisim"
  "fr": "frenchname"
}
```

When I get the data, when I want only the "tr" place in the mlgName, or I want to include the "tr" and "en" places

latest version like this.  **BUT What I want to do here should not be to remove the "fr"** I want to get what I want as a key, like saying "en" and "tr" ones should come

need this

```
 parentid:2,
    id:4,
    mlgName : {
      "en": "englishname"
      "tr": "turkceisim"
    }
```

Comment: Unclear. Please explain.

Comment: If I want to write aggregation, how can I get the data in mongo db? Get the values ​​I want in mlgName. quite clear  " Aggregation code " @Gibbs